# Couchbase Search key-values

Tags: couchbase

How can i implement search in Couchbase using CB views. I don't want to use elastic search for search. what would be the best approach to search documents on the basis of value. For example below is my document. I want to implement search on the basis of name,city,state and country.

```
{
  "_id": "location::370794",
  "name": "Kenai Riverside Fishing",
  "description": "Welcome to the Kenai Riverside Fishing program at Kenai Riverside Lodge, your destination for incredible Alaska fishing experiences. Kenai Riverside Fishing is part of Alaska Wildland Adventures, a long-time  operator of guided fishing trips since 1977. Our trips explore the world-famous Kenai River for freshwater species, like king and sockeye salmon, rainbow trout and Dolly Varden. We also  fish Resurrection Bay for halibut and silver salmon. Whether you are a seasoned angler or a first time fisherman, we’ll put you on the fish!",
  "city": "Cooper Landing",
  "state": "Alaska",
  "country": "USA",
}
```

How can i achieve this using couchbase views?

Answer (score 3):

**if you can, use N1QL**

Have you looked into the newly released Couchbase Server 4.0 and especially `N1QL`?

This is a very powerful query language (superset of SQL) that would allow you to query your documents using any combinations, including eg. `state` AND `city`, etc...

You can set up secondary indexes on fields you are most likely to query for better performance, and you get a lot of flexibility!

**If you really want to stick with views**

To answer your question about views, if what you want is to be able to query by choosing only one out of your 4 criterias, what you would have to do is to build 4 views (one per criteria). Each view would map a document to the corresponding criteria. For example, with country:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if (doc.country) {
    emit(doc.country, null);
  }
}
```

The `if` checks that the field is actually there. If you have several document types in you bucket, maybe you also want to filter on adequate document type (eg. by checking that the prefix of the `_id` attribute is `location::` in your example).

Searching would then just be a matter of querying the correct view out of the 4, providing the `key` to search for, eg. `france`. Note: maybe you want to emit a `toUpperCase()` version of the data so that search is case-insensitive (you'd have to uppercase the lookup key when querying as well).

**Documentation**

For generic information (from a dev's perspective) about querying with Couchbase, have a look at the developer's guide on [N1QL](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/developer-guide/querying.html) and [Views](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/developer-guide/views-intro.html).

Please also refer to the [documentation of your SDK](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/sdks/intro.html) to find out how to query `views` and/or `N1QL` in your favorite language.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can not use N1QL because I am using 3.0.1 Community Edition which does not support N1QL.  
second using Views I can use 
**

`function (doc, meta) {
    emit(doc.city, null);
    emit(doc.state, null);
    emit(doc.country, null);
}`
**
1. I want to match Substring  in SQL like operator
2. It is also case sensitive. I don't want this.

Comment: fair point you can do 4 emits in a single view... for substrings, view are limited to prefix search (equivalent to `LIKE 'prefix%'`), through a trick. To ignore case, emit an uppercase version of the key in your map function, apply the same process to the key criteria when querying.

Comment: By the way if you are not in production yet, I would immediately jump to CB 4.0.0 Community Edition and use `N1QL`. Even if I was in production, I would seriously consider it (with more planning) ;)

Comment: can you please more elaborate sub-string search view? I could not get 'prefix%'? Sample code would be much appreciated. thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: ah yes this was a nod to SQL... the way to do that with a view is by passing startkey and endkey arguments, with a little unicode trick: for example `startkey` being `"theEmail"` then `endkey` would be `"theEmail\uEFFF"`.
Here `\uEFFF` is a unicode char high enough in the alphanumeric order that there is no other word starting with "myEmail" that would be sorted after "myEmail\uEFFF", so you can use that as the closing side of your range. for instance in urlencoded form : `http://localhost:8092/default/_design/test/_view/map?startkey=%22barb%22&endkey=%22barb%5Cuefff%22`